Django manage.py migration related commands not returning anything
I had an issue with migrations in a project I'm working on, a migration was deleted manually and the sync was ruined, I tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked and at the end I decided to backup the DB and delete all migrations and drop the django_migrations table from the MySQL db, now when I try to run any command like python manage.py makemigrations or python manage.py migrate nothing appears in stdout or stderr, absolutely nothing, not even an error, which has been puzzling me
I can provide any information needed but I don't really know where to start here really, Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Have you tried python manage.py makemigrations appname

What is your file structure? Once we see that, I'm guessing an answer is written to solve this below with __init__. If you aren't clearing data and starting from fresh you will need to run migrations with --fake as you are placing migrations in the django_migrations table but your DB is already migrated. The idea of migrations is a sync between code and your DB, if your DB is already set but your migrations are wrong, you need to fake them. There are quite a bit of solutions posted here for that if you need help

What's the backup format? Json?

You need to create
app_name/migrations/__init__.py
for every app you have.
or instead you can run:
python manage.py makemigrations app_name

Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps
I would try the following command for each table and see what its output is for models.py, and then compare the models it creates to the ones you have in your project and correct your project models if needed to match:
python manage.py inspectdb tablename

If running this command doesn't work, there is probably another issue with the database connection. If it works and the models are corrected, you should then run the following:
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial

This will make the initial migration but not apply changes because the tables already exist.
